# what is absolute file path in windows machine using java?

Tags: java, windows, file

I am refering file path in two places in my program. In one place, i pass file path in FileInputStream and in another place i pass to Spring getResource() method.

If i give file path in FileInputStream like "`file:/C:/myfile`" it is throwing error. I had to give `C:\\myfile`.

But in getResource() method, if i give `C:\\myfile`  it is throwing error i had to give `file:/C:/myfile`.

Why this difference? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`FileInputStream` is taking a `String` representing file path. `getResource()` from Spring is taking URL string representation of the resource.**

Those two are not the same.